# Custom Authorization filter not firing default code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using a custom authorization filter but when I use the built in stuff for roles it no longer works. How can I use the custom filter attribute but still have the existing functionality fire to ensure it doesn't interfere with the standard [Authorize] attribute should I make a custom name one instead so the [Authorize] still fires.

```
public class AuthorizeActionFilter : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IAuthorizationFilter
{
private readonly string _permission;

public AuthorizeActionFilter(string permission)
{
  _permission = permission;
}

public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
   bool isAuthorized = CheckUserPermission(context.HttpContext.User, _permission);
   if (!isAuthorized)
   {
      context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
   }
}
private bool CheckUserPermission(ClaimsPrincipal user, string permission)
{
     // Logic for checking the user permission goes here. 

     // Let's assume this user has only read permission.
     return permission == "Read";
}
}

}
```

Any help would be apricate If I would be better creating a custom name one how do i go about that in the same manor as of above?.

Also how does one have the attirubute in such as way i can do Thanks.

```
[HasPermssions(Permissions = "Create,Read,Update")]
```

Also how does one access the name of the controller / action method it was called on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logic wrong in custom loop on permissions authorization filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67548250/logic-wrong-in-custom-loop-on-permissions-authorization-filter)

Comment: U basically copied it into my own question