# Logic wrong in custom loop on permissions authorization filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm getting false positives here. Basically, what I want to happen is only return an error if, for example, the user does not have permission to do `Create`—but currently it's returning an error even when they have that permission.

| User | Permission | Active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Create | True |
| 12 | Update | False |
| 12 | Delete | True |

#### First Example

The following should return `true`. It does, but it's a false positive because `Read`, `Update`, and `Delete` are not present.

```
[HasPermission("Create");
```

#### Second Example

Should return `false`, but it is *also* returning that `Read` and `Delete` are not present when I am only asking for `Create` and `Update`:

```
[HasPermission("Create,Update");
```

#### Code

```
string[] permissionValues = permission.Split(",");
Dictionary<string, bool> dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

foreach (var item in permissionValues)
{
    var permissions = db.AppWarehouseUserPermmissions.Any(w => w.Name == item && w.Controller == controllerName && w.isAcitve == true);
    dict.Add(item, permissions);
}
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    if (item.Key == "Create" || item.Key == "Read" || item.Key == "Update" || item.Key == "Delete" && item.Value == true)
    {
        isAuthorised = true;
               
    }
    if (item.Key == "Create" || item.Key == "Read" || item.Key=="Update" || item.Key=="Delete" && item.Value==false)
    {                                        
            _customError.Add(new CutomError() { Message = $"User has no {item.Key} permissions", ErrorCode = item.Key });
    }
}
return isAuthorised;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up placing the logic in a unit test and got it to work sometimes the best position is take the code out of the master issue and work on it line by line in the unit test.

This now works as expected but i feel it could be done better.

```
 public void Setup()
 {
   permissionsList = new List<AppWarehouseUserPermmissions>(){
    new AppWarehouseUserPermmissions {
        Name="Create",
        Action="Create",
        Controller="StockItems",            
        isAcitve=true            
        //populate other properties  
    }, new AppWarehouseUserPermmissions {
        Name="Update",
        Action="Update",
        Controller="StockItems",
        isAcitve=false            
        //populate other properties  
    },new AppWarehouseUserPermmissions {
        Name="Delete",
        Action="Delete",
        Controller="StockItems",
        isAcitve=true            
        //populate other properties  
    },
       new AppWarehouseUserPermmissions
      {
          Name = "Read",
          Action = "Read",
          Controller = "Test",
          isAcitve = true
          //populate other properties  
      }
     };
     };
  }

[TestCase("Create,Update", "StockItems", 1)]
[TestCase("Delete,Update", "StockItems", 1)]
[TestCase("Read,Update", "StockItems", 2)]
[TestCase("Update", "StockItems", 1)]

public void Vlaidate_Permissions_Returns_Corrrect_Errors(string permission,string controllerName,int expected)
{
        bool isAuthorised = false;
        List<CutomError> _customError = new List<CutomError>();
        string[] permissionValues = permission.Split(",");
        Dictionary<string, bool> dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

        foreach (var item in permissionValues)
        {
            var permissions = permissionsList.Any(w => w.Name == item && w.Controller == controllerName && w.isAcitve == true);
            dict.Add(item, permissions);
        }
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            if (item.Key == "Create" || item.Key == "Read" || item.Key == "Update" || item.Key == "Delete" && item.Value == true)
            {
                isAuthorised = true;

            }
           
        }
        foreach (var item in dict.Where(w => w.Value == false))
        {
            _customError.Add(new CutomError() { Message = $"Uwas has no {item.Key} permissions", ErrorCode = item.Key });
        }
        
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, _customError.Count);
    }
}
```